# Parse output received from web services of Moodle

Tags: php, json, moodle

How to distinguish between these 2 outputs I received in PHP?

The following responses are what I get after

1. Sucessful registration of user

   ```
   (
       [0] => stdClass Object
           (
               [id] => 9
               [username] => mathewgil111
           )
   )
   ```
2. Invalid login

   ```
   (
       [exception] => invalid_parameter_exception
       [errorcode] => invalidparameter
       [message] => Invalid parameter value detected
       [debuginfo] => Username already exists: mathewgil111
   )
   ```

What I want to do is to redirect user depending on the output I get.

Comment: And your efforts till now are?

Comment: used foreach loop based on keyvalue pair but it works for the 2nd not for the first

Comment: please share the code.

Answer (score 0):

See I execute a webservice.After sucessfull creation of user 
I get following json

```
[{
    "id": 10,
    "username": "mathew1111"
}]
```

And after failed registration I get this

```
{
    "exception": "invalid_parameter_exception",
    "errorcode": "invalidparameter",
    "message": "Invalid parameter value detected",
    "debuginfo": "Username already exists: mathew111"
}
```

$resp contains that json

```
<?php
    $resp = $curl->post($serverurl . $restformat, $params);
    print_r($resp);
    $str = json_decode($resp);
    print_r($str);
?>
```